# Visual Studio compiled program doesn't initialize properly after trying to decrease output size

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compilation, linker, program-entry-point

I was trying to make a simple C++ program and compile it with Visual Studio with options that decrease its size significantly.

The code is:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return argc;
}
```

The commandline is:

```
cl /O1 /GS- /Oi- test.cpp /link /nodefaultlib /safeseh:no /filealign:512 /entry:main /subsystem:console /MERGE:.rdata=.text
```

The program compiles and links without warning. It runs but instead of returning the number of arguments, it returns random numbers from the memory.

It seems like the problem is that the heap is not initialized and arguments are not parsed like they should be normally in the startup of the windows program. What could be the mistake I am making?

**EDIT:** The answers below are both correct, and were posted at the same time, so I won't accept one, however they did help me, and by linking my program with kernel32.lib and shell32.lib the problem was fixed.

Comment: _"What could be the mistake I am making?"_ Coming up with this idea in the first place ^_^ What is your actual goal? What is the actual problem that you're trying to solve with this hackery?

Comment: FWIW, passing `/FIXED` to the linker will shave another kilobyte off, because the `.reloc` section is omitted.  Documentation suggests that's the default when building an EXE but... testing shows otherwise.

Comment: Testing also shows that `/safeseh:no` and `/merge` have no effect on size, at least with the C++ compiler and linker that ship in VS2017.  Please also consider `/Os` (optimize for size) rather than `/O1`.

Comment: @BenVoigt thanks for the optimization advice!

Comment: I just noticed your comment @BoundaryImposition . The reason why I am doing this is because the same code I posted here normally compiled to the size of 79kb and when I finally got everything working I managed to decrease it to 1536 bytes which is around 50 times smaller. I needed this to run a executable higher than 5gb. What I did is I disassembled the 5.4gb exe, changed it to c++ code, then compiled it this way, and a 5.4gb turned into a 4.8gb file which can be run on windows. Why do i have an exe that is 5.4gb is an another crazy story with my experiments so i won't go in depth :)

Answer (score 3):

Initialization of `argc` and `argv` is performed by C runtime. With `/nodefaultlib` option they are left uninitialized. You can still retrieve command line arguments yourself using `GetCommandLineW` and `CommandLineToArgvW`.

Comment: It's caused by `/ENTRY`, not `/NODEFAULTLIB`.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Presumably without `/ENTRY` there would still be a problem caused by `/NODEFAULTLIB`, because the entrypoint from which the OP has opted out still wouldn't actually exist.

Comment: @BoundaryImposition: But the other way around is entirely possible -- using `/ENTRY` and still linking the language runtime -- and in such case, the problem will still occur.  Therefore, it isn't caused by `/NODEFAULTLIB`

Comment: @BenVoigt: Indeed. It's caused by both. You're both right. There's no need for a fight.

Comment: I linked my program with kernel32.lib and shell32.lib and now everything works fine. The GetCommandLineW and CommandLineToArgvW found in those libraries were missing as you said. Thank you.

Comment: @KKZiomek you can declare entry point as `void __cdecl mainCRTStartup(void)` (default entry point by VC++) so there will be no need to explicitly specify `/entry`.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, arguments are not parsed, because that's part of the language runtime library entry point, and you've substituted your own using the `/ENTRY` linker option.

Call `GetCommandLineW` and `CommandLineToArgvW` functions found in Windows-provided DLLs in order to get the normal `argv` and `argc` values.

Comment: Which specific libraries could I find those calls in?

Comment: kernel32 and shell32

Comment: I linked my program with kernel32.lib and shell32.lib and now everything works fine. Thank you.